# The computations of Linear Discriminant Analysis in package 'MASS' for p>n matrices

Tags: r, lda

In the R package 'MASS' I'm using the function 'lda'. I'm trying to find documentation on the specific way that this function handles matrices with more variables than observations (in this case using moment estimation of the covariance matrix). Looking at the code, it seems like it utilizes the singular value decomposition of the covariance matrix, but the exact way it does this is lost on me. If someone knows any reference for this method it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you look in the Venables and Ripley book that the library is written for ... ?